# SQL. How convert variable into sting?

Tags: sql

I tried to use `RAISERROR(Cast (select @HostelId as varchar(50))`   to show my variable on Raiserror. But I have no idea how to convert sql variable into string.

```
Declare @HostelId int=0;
Declare @Hostels Cursor;

SET @Hostels  = cursor for select Hostel.HostelCode
From  Hostel

Open @Hostels 
While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Fetch next from @Hostels into @HostelId
Begin 
    RAISERROR(Cast (select @HostelId as varchar(50)), 0,0);
End
Close @Hostels
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a format string for the message string parameter like this:

```
RAISERROR('%d', 0,0, @HostelId);
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments)

```
Open @Hostels
Fetch next from @Hostels into @HostelId
While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin 
    RAISERROR('%d', 0,0, @HostelId);
    Fetch next from @Hostels into @HostelId
End
Close @Hostels
```

Comment: Tell me, please, how to output the results in turn? When I run the query, I only get the last result from the loop.

Comment: @AshenOne Do you just want to print the values? Why do you use raiseerror?

Comment: Because I read that when using RAISERROR the output is not erased, but I was wrong